# pyspark zipWithIndex() to DataFrame - type of column changed

Tags: pyspark

I have a Spark DataFrame. Following is the code to generate an example of the dataframe.

```
     arr = np.array([
['b5ad805c-f295-4852-82fc-961a88',12732936],
['0FD6955D-484C-4FC8-8C3F-DA7D28','Gklb38'],
['0E3D17EA-BEEF-4931-8104',12909841],
['CC2877D0-A15C-4C0A-AD65-762A35C1','12645715'],
['CC2877D0-A15C-4C0A-AD65-762A35C1',12909837],
['6AC9C45D-A891-4BEA-92B1-04224E9C65ED', '12894376'],
['CFF7BAB7-C5E1-490D-B257-AE58CA071362', 'Gklb38' ]])

df_purchases = pd.DataFrame(arr, columns = ['user_id','basket'])
df_spark = spark.createDataFrame(df_purchases)
df_spark.show()
```

In an attempt to create indexes for each unique product_id (basket), I used `zipWithIndex()`

```
products_only = spark_df[['basket']]
products_df = products_only.distinct()
indexed_products = products_df.rdd.zipWithIndex()
```

And then I converted back to DataFrame type:

```
# convert to spark data frame
products_ind_df = indexed_products.toDF(["product_id", "index"])
```

When I checked the type, I found that it's:

```
products_ind_df.dtypes
```

Output:

```
[('product_id', 'struct<basket:string>'), ('index', 'bigint')]
```

whereas :

```
products_df.dtypes
```

Outputs:

```
 [('basket', 'string')]
```

My question is why the type isn't:

```
[('product_id', 'string'), ('index', 'bigint')]
```

and how to change it to string?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `products_df.rdd` is a RDD of Row object, you need to extract the `basket` from each row as a String first:

```py
products_df.rdd.map(lambda r: r.basket).zipWithIndex().toDF(['product_id', 'index'])
# DataFrame[product_id: string, index: bigint]
```

---

Besides if you simply need to map each product id to an integer, you can also use the `StringIndexer` from `ml.feature` module:

```py
from pyspark.ml.feature import StringIndexer
from pyspark.sql.functions import col

stringIndexer = StringIndexer(inputCol="basket", outputCol="index")
model = stringIndexer.fit(df_spark)
df_spark_index = model.transform(df_spark).withColumn("index", col("index").cast("int"))

df_spark_index.show()
+--------------------+--------+-----+
|             user_id|  basket|index|
+--------------------+--------+-----+
|b5ad805c-f295-485...|12732936|    2|
|0FD6955D-484C-4FC...|  Gklb38|    0|
|0E3D17EA-BEEF-493...|12909841|    1|
|CC2877D0-A15C-4C0...|12645715|    5|
|CC2877D0-A15C-4C0...|12909837|    3|
|6AC9C45D-A891-4BE...|12894376|    4|
|CFF7BAB7-C5E1-490...|  Gklb38|    0|
+--------------------+--------+-----+
```

Comment: Thank you! I want to have indexes for product_id and indexes for user_id because I need to use these indexes in order to create a CoordinateMatrix of purchases (whether a customer bought that product or not => 1 or 0). What's the difference in terms of optimization/performance between creating index using `rdd.zipWithIndex()` as I wanted VS using `StringIndexer`? I didn't know about this `ml.feature` library, first.